# Trying to start zoneminder 1.28 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, zoneminder

I just installed zoneminder v1.28.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to start it but in the log I get the following message, "Can't create missing temporary directory '/var/run/zm': Permission denied". I've searched the internet and can't find anything to fix this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but not many straight forward answers out there so...

Every reboot I have to do this, but it gets Zoneminder running.

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/zm -p && sudo chmod 777 /var/run/zm/
```

Or 
`sudo mkdir /var/run/zm -p && sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/run/zm/`

Then start

for me, its not a real risk to do either one of these, but you should check your own security needs before choosing.

Comment: You could add this to `.bashrc` but the problem is with the installer of ZM where they did not use `sudo` with a command that does require it. It probably should be installed in a location that does not require `sudo` and then it will run (like /home/$USER/ or /opt/ with an open directory to that user)